# Visualizing order 3 mapping class of genus 2 surface

Tags: surfaces, geometric-topology

Let $\Sigma_2$ be a closed genus $2$ surface.  There exists an orientation-preserving diffeomorphism $f:\Sigma_2 \rightarrow \Sigma_2$ of order $3$.  The diffeomorphism has $4$ fixed points (each, of course, of order $3$) and from Riemann-Hurewitz you can see that the quotient is a sphere $S^2$.

To construct $f$, it is enough to construct the appropriate branched cover of $S^2$.  But this is easy: let $p_1,\ldots,p_4$ be $4$ distinct points of $S^2$ and let $X = S^2 \setminus \{p_1,\ldots,p_4\}$.  There then exists a surjection $\phi:H_1(X;\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/3$ which for all $1 \leq i \leq 4$ takes a loop around $p_i$ to a generator of $\mathbb{Z}/3$.  Let $\widetilde{X}$ be the degree $3$ regular cover of $X$ associated to $\phi$.  Then an Euler characteristic calculation shows that $\widetilde{X}$ is diffeomorphic to a genus $2$ surface minus $4$ point.  The desired branched cover $\Sigma_2 \rightarrow S^2$ is then obtained by filling in these $4$ points.

I am having trouble visualizing the above construction.  I can work everything out and e.g. construct a triangulation of $\Sigma_2$ that is preserved by $f$, but I cannot "see" $f$.  Is there a picture of this diffeomorphism somewhere, or at least a more visual way of understanding it?

Answer (score 3):

With the assistance of [Big Bird](https://img1.etsystatic.com/028/0/8333715/il_570xN.632679807_ftbd.jpg). Look carefully at one of his "feet", and imagine it spinning. Let me know if you need a few more hints...

Comment: I really like your answer!!!